# User string input validation and exception error

Tags: java

I'm new in Java programming and I'm trying to create a user input validation to make sure that the user only input one of the three possible strings: Mammals, Reptiles, Birds. But I'm stock on trying to validate and create a loop. So far I have this:

```
    public void validName() {
         Scanner typeInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String [] type = {"Mammals", "Reptiles", "Birds"};

        System.out.println("Enter Animal Type: ");
        String atype = typeInput.next();
        try {
        if
            (!Arrays.asList(type).contains(atype)){
            System.out.println("Not a correct animal");   
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e+"Plase add the correct Animal Type: (Mammals, Reptile, or Bird");
        atype= typeInput.nextLine();}

        while (atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Mammals") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Reptile") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Birds"));
        { System.out.println("Continue to next step");}

        }
}
```

When I run the previous code I get this output:

```
Please enter First Name
Cris
Please enter Last Name
Cruz
User logged In: Criz Cruz
Welcome to ZooOrganizer!
Enter Animal Type: 
Cow
Not a correct animal
Continue to next step
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't get to execute the Catch Exception neither the loop to make the user to input the animal type again.

```
public void validName() {
         Scanner typeInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String [] type = {"Mammals", "Reptiles", "Birds"};

        System.out.println("Enter Animal Type: ");
        String atype = typeInput.next();
        try {
        if
            (!Arrays.asList(type).contains(atype)){
            System.out.println("Not a correct animal");   
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e+"Plase add the correct Animal Type: (Mammals, Reptile, or Bird");
        atype= typeInput.nextLine();}

        while (atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Mammals") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Reptile") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Birds"));
        { System.out.println("Continue to next step");}

        }
}
```

Comment: You need to throw the Exception when your program goes into your if statement mate, right now it goes in, prints the error message and the program keeps going because no throw exception, throw it after the message.. throw new Exception(); and inside the () you can put a message :)

Comment: This is not how try-catch works. What you're looking for is a normal if-else. And the loop needs to be around everything, starting from *"Enter Animal Type: "*.

Comment: @Gendarme Thanks for the comment. Like I said, I'm new in Java and I've working in this "simple" scenario for the last two days and still don't understand the loop and catch syntax. I have used both scenarios try-catch and if-else, but I still missing to get what I want, I still couldn't get the Exception to execute. What's making it harder to me is to valide Strings instead of Integers for example.

Comment: if you put in a correct animal, it looks to me like the while loop as you have written it is going to run forever. I know that's what @gendarme said, too, but the reason is that the condition evaluates to to true and nothing happens within the loop as it is now that could change that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to think about it, the prompt you have coded is actually rather cruel. It doesn't inform the User of what is expected as input. You may as well display a prompt like:

```
Hey, enter an Animal Type and if you guess it right 
you get two free OH-Henry Bars (yum yum): -->
```

Be up-front with what is required from the User and if you can, make the entry as simple as possible. If you do then the errors that can be possibly produced by that User is almost completely eliminated, for example:

```
Enter an Animal Type (Mammals, Reptiles, Birds): -->
```

Now the User can see what input you're expecting. This however still has issues which your code would need to deal with and take care of such as spelling mistakes, improper letter case, no word entered, etc. In my opinion it's sort of actually a pain in the butt to have to write the word **Reptile** into something like a Console Application which is why I would avoid those applications, you know :

```
Enter the full path and file name to your Database located within 
the Windows Documents folder: -->
```

Ya, I don't think so....next app.

When you have multiple items that can be entered then use a Menu System. This way the User can see the choices available and only needs to enter a single letter or number for the desired menu item, for example:

```
Select an Animal Type (1-3): 
1) Mammal
2) Reptiles
3) Birds
4) Quit
Menu Choice: -->
```

Doing it this way also reduces the amount of code required to carry out validity. Is the entered menu choice an Integer Number, is the entry greater than or equal to 1 and is it less than or equal to 4. If not then tell the User of non-validity and loop again. Here is how you might do this with your current scheme:

```
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
Scanner typeInput = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] type = {"Mammals", "Reptiles", "Birds"};
String selectedAnimalType = "";
String atype = "";

// Start a prompt WHILE loop...
while (atype.equals("")) {
    /* Display a Menu. Doing things this way doesn't leave 
       the User in the dark as to what is required for input. */
    System.out.print("Select an Animal Type (1-3): " + ls
                     + "1) Mammal" + ls + "2) Reptiles" + ls 
                     + "3) Birds" + ls + "4) Quit" + ls
                     + "Menu Choice: --> ");

    // Get User input...
    atype = typeInput.nextLine();

    // Is the Input a Valid menu choice?
    if (!atype.matches("\\d") || Integer.valueOf(atype) < 1 || Integer.valueOf(atype) > 4) {
        /* If it's not a string representation of a Integer numerical value OR
           if it's a numerical value less than 1 OR if it's a numerical value
           greater than 4                */                
        System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please try again..." + ls);
        atype = "";  // Make atype equal null string ("") to continue WHILE loop
    }
    // Otherwise, was the menu choice the numerical value 4 to quit?
    else if (Integer.valueOf(atype) == 4) {
        // Yes, it was...
        System.out.println("Quiting... Bye-Bye");
        System.exit(0);   // Quit (end) Application.
    }
}
// Prompt loop successful...continue on with code.

/* Get the proper name for the Animal Type from the 'type' Array
   based on the menu choice (numerical value minus 1) so as to get 
   the desired array index value.                   */
selectedAnimalType = type[Integer.valueOf(atype) - 1];

/* The condition for the below WHILE loop is redundant since we 
   would NEVER get this far unless a menu choice for either Mammal, 
   Reptiles, or Birds, was made, so don't bother using it. Do something 
   similar as to what was done in the first prompt loop above.     */
while (atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Mammals") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Reptile") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Birds")) {
    System.out.println("Continue to next step");
    // ........................................
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you for taking the time to do a decent explanation with examples. I was overthinking the code I was using, trying to validate `String` when it was way easier for me using `Integer` like the Menu you proposed. I finally achieved what I was trying. 
**Thanks for the help**

Answer (score -1):

You should use a Do...While loop in this case:

```
public void validName() {
        Scanner typeInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String [] type = {"Mammals", "Reptiles", "Birds"};

        do {
        System.out.println("Enter Animal Type: ");
        String atype = typeInput.next();
        try {
        if
            (!Arrays.asList(type).contains(atype)){
            System.out.println("Not a correct animal");   
            System.out.println("Continue to next step");}
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e+"Plase add the correct Animal Type: (Mammals, Reptile, or Bird");
        atype= typeInput.nextLine();}

        } while (atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Mammals") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Reptile") || atype.equalsIgnoreCase("Birds"));

}
```

Comment: I think the down vote must be for not throwing something to activate the catch or for not just incorporating its message into  the if block and getting rid of the reading next line)